# Proving $\arg$ restricted to an open subset of $S^1$ is smooth

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $U$ be an open subset of $S^1\subset \mathbb{R}^2$.
Define $\theta:U\to \mathbb{R}$ by $\theta(x,y)=\arg(x+iy)$ where $\arg$ is the principal argument. I want to prove that $\theta$ is smooth (i.e. that partial derivatives of all orders exist and are continuous).

I can compute partial derivatives for various different cases.

For example, if $x>0$ then $\partial_x\theta=\partial_x(\arctan(y/x))=-\dfrac{y}{x^2+y^2}$, $\partial_x^2\theta=\dfrac{2xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$, and so on.

But this approach seems to be a lot of work. Is there an easier way to show $\theta$ is smooth?

Comment: The problem is that the principal argument (whether you define it in $[0,2\pi]$ or $[-\pi,\pi]$ as both are popular options for the name principal argument) is discontinuous with fixed discontinuity at $1$ or $-1$, so if $U$ contains that point, the result is just not true; what is true is that for any $U \ne S^1$ there is $V$ open in the plane containing $U$ s.t you can choose the argument to be harmonic (hence real analytic, hence the conclusion) on $V$ hence on $U$

Comment: Usually the principal argument takes values in $(-\pi,\pi).$ is this what you mean?

Comment: @zhw Does it make any difference whether it takes values in $(-\pi,\pi]$ or $[0,2\pi)$?

Comment: Not really, but you are going to run into problems with those  half open intervals. Better to stick with $(0,2\pi)$ or $(-\pi,\pi).$ Note there is no continuous $\arg$ for the case $U=S^1.$